# Magento - override core review module to add all store when adding review from frontend

Tags: php, magento

I have a requirement to add all store when adding new rating and review of a product. I am able to do this by editing the core file.

the file is

> app\code\core\Mage\Review\controllers\ProductController.php

I need to make the changes into the `postAction()` function.

Now, the question is **how can I make this thing inside the local folder?**

I have created a new module "My_Module_review" inside the local folder.

Following steps I followed to create the module.

Step 1:

Added My_Module_Review.xml inside app/etc/module folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module_Review>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module_Review>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2:
Created config.xml inside app/code/local/My/Module/Review/etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module_Review>
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </My_Module_Review>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <review>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Module_Review before="Mage_Review">My_Module_Review</Module_Review>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </review>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Step 3:
Created ProductController.php file inside app/code/local/My/Module/Review/controllers/ProductController.php

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Review').DS.'ProductController.php');
class My_Module_Review_ProductController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
{


 public function indexAction() {
     print_r($_POST);exit;

 }
}
```

but nothing is happening when I am posting review. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Look at the section rewrite controllers http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/
If you need something specific - edit your question and put comment here.

Comment: I have modified my question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly fix this: app/code/local/{Vendor}/{Module name}/. Better use smth like this: app/code/local/Company/Survey. If you use Review - you can be confused due identical module names. Keep it simple

Comment: Issue is solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with incorrect module structure:

You need to use

> app/code/local/{Vendor}/{Module name}/

instead of posted above in first topic.

Also my advice is do not duplicate magento module names even if they have different names in config.xml. Example of module naming:

> app/code/local/Company/Survey

More details about basic folder structure: http://inchoo.net/magento/basic-folder-structure-for-new-magento-module/